# Why is my website is not responding to my JS script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use JavaScript so when you click on the menubars icon, the whole menu appears when opening the website on a phone using Google. (when device width is larger than 470px, menubars have a display: none)

This is the necessary html:

```
 <div id="menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" style='font-size:36px; color: white' id="menubars"></i>
        <nav>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
 </div>
```

This is the css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 470px) {

    body{
        background-image: none;
    }



    #menu {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        z-index: 3;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        width: 75%;
        background-color: black;
        transform: translate(-195px, 0);
    }

    #menubars {
        display: initial;
    }
```

and this is the JS:

```
const menubars =document.getElementById("menubars");
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");


menubars.addEventListener("touch", function() {
    menu.style.borderRight = "white thin";
    menu.style.transform = "translate(195px)";
});
```

I know the script is linked correctly because I can see the event listener when clicking inspect element.

[website opened with devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCoYj.png)

The website is :

https://maria-shn.github.io/Portfolio

I am new to JS and I know there is probably a better way to achieve my goal but I would like to understand why it is not working.

Comment: where did you hear of the event `touch`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events it looks more structured than that. I never used those anyway so I can't be more helpful than this. Are you sure you couldn't just use `click`?

Comment: There is no `touch` event in JS, jQuery has it.

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK there is no `touch` event, there are `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove` and `touchcancel`. If you put a breakpoint inside your event handler, you can see it is never triggered. (maybe try first with `click` event, since this is hidden on desktop anyway...)
2. The `border-right` value is missing what kind of line you want to present (solid, dashed, etc.) ([explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp))

3. Not sure if this is what you intended, but `translate(195px)` will translate both the X and Y positions, you can use `translateX()` (or Y) to move just one

Comment: Thank you ! it worked with the click event. I also used your other suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

we don't have touch event, you can see about touchcancel, touchend, touchmove, touchstart. We can start testing by click.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the click event works!

Comment: I feel good for helping you

Comment: you fully change intention of question asker saying use `click` which is not good, he/she use `touch` some purposely so you have to suggest touch related events.